# Is it important to fix all warnings, notices, errors?

Tags: php, error-handling

Is it important to handle all warnings when you're writing code?  A dev who has more seniority in my company insists the warnings are harmless.  Admittedly, some of them are:

> Warning:  Division by zero
>
> Notice:  Undefined index

Sometimes these errors aren't affecting logical output, but it's making it really hard for me to debug.  We're writing in PHP he's developing directly on our production server that has error reporting turned off.  When I pull the code onto my local machine I get hundreds/thousands of warnings like this.  I'm not confident that this is best practice, and I don't want to pick up bad habits.  I'm looking for a second opinion on best practices.

Comment: Why would you leave your code in a state where you could have difficult to find bugs? Or even have bugs at all?

Comment: Errors like that should definitely be fixed if you want to be able to rely on your code. Ignoring those errors seems like a disaster waiting to happen.

Comment: _"A dev ... insists the warnings are harmless"_ / _"he's developing directly on our production server"_ **so many red flags**

Comment: Think it like this. Instead of vacuum  clean your apartment you collect all the dirt and put it under the carpet. It may be "ok" for a month of even for a few months if you are lucky but in the end you are the one who has to finally clean the apartment. Errors/Notices/Warnings are there for a reason to inform you that something is not right. Treat them as such and don't just act like they don't exist.

Comment: At a moment you'll rewrite some code, just a little bit, a weird bug will appear in a specific case. You'll find it later and it could do bad stuff to your application. If you take the time necessary to write code without warning/error you avoid `technical debt`, in fact you win time.

Comment: short answer: yes it is.

Answer (score 1):

As all people above correctly commented, there are some red flags, and technical debt is the issue.
He's senior and there may be also the explanation in it:
Probably he ended up over time with so much warnings and notices, that now he's too lazy to fix everything as it should, because it would take him a lot of time for something which he'll have troubles to explain to his boss.

In other words, it kind of depends on the amount, size of the program, project parameters (timelines), budget etc.
As most people say: If it's hundreds and hundreds of warnings then it's too much.
But for my oppinion: if it's just 3 deprecation notices, then it's not too urgent (take into account that PHP production versions get upgraded all 5-10 years).

If we put our grounding cable on: Programmers reality is sometimes harsh. In the best world you don't let accumulate so much technical debt and fix these warnings and notices on the way. But sometimes, it's a 10 year old program originally written for an older PHP version and was upgraded for newer versions with very low budget. Under these circumstancies it's not always programmers faults when some incompatibilities or warnings arise. 
We like to talk about ideal worlds but often forget that we don't always get budget and time we need.
What I want to say is: Ask your boss and present them the problem. They'll take the executive decision: Go ahead fix warnings, or: "stop: We don't want you to invest time into issues that are "not critical", the app/site works without errors and as planned, we want you to spend time into enhancements not to fix something which apparently is not producing catastrophic failures." or perhaps the answer is "don't do anything at the moment, PHP7 will be soon introduced and all programs will get money to fix errors then, just wait with these cases" or "well app will be soon not needed anyomore. Just leave as is"

At least that's the way such situations arise. To clean everything up would be great, but sometimes the project conditions are not there to do so and loose time fixing something which is actually not really broken.